# Installing two outdoor receptacles using T LB pvc, How many ground wires?

Tags: electrical, outdoor, pvc

I am looking to put a general use swimming pool receptacle at my fence and then the dedicated pool receptacle by the pump, each on its own gfci circuit.

The general use would come first in the raceway. I originally thought I would have to branch off to the general use receptacle, and feed the dedicated pool circuit wires up to that receptacle and back down to a seperate pvc conduit and continue back to the swimming pool pump receptacle.

Is there anything wrong with using a T pvc LB, to split off?  So at the T the tge neutral and hot for general use will go left, and the swimming pool pump circuit will run straight and head on its way to that receptacle.

If so, how would I run the ground wire? Would I need two seperate ground wires?

[T LB](https://m.grainger.com/mobile/product/4FYL6?cm_mmc=PPC:%20Google%20PLA&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!166587909811!!!!269396336603!&ef_id=WWWNoAAAAfnn1BzC:20170914124538:s&kwid=productads-adid%5E166587909811-device%5Em-plaid%5E269396336603-sku%5E4FYL6-adType%5EPLA)

Running the trencher this weekend and trying to plan the dig currently.

Answer (score 2):

That conduit body is not large enough to contain a splice. You'll have to either run two grounds, or find a different place to splice.

**References:**

- National Electrical Code 2017 314.16(C)(2); Allows splices, taps, and devices in conduit bodies, but only if the volume is stamped on it and it's large enough.
- National Electrical Code 2017 314.16(B); Says that the CB would have to be at least 11.25 cu.in. to have a splice. (4 pass through conductors + grounds = 5 fill units. 5 * 2.25 = 11.25).

At least that's how I interpret the code.

Comment: Forgot to mention, this will be 10 guage wire in 3/4 pvc conduit. Can I pig tail the ground in the general use receptical and run it back down to the T LB and on its way to the pool pump receptacle?

Comment: So ground will run up to general use, pig tail to be used for general use receptacle, and then run back down the way it came up back to the T LB

Comment: There's no problem splicing in the receptacle box.

Comment: Okay thanks! So I can run the ground back down the same pvc pipe it came up and back to the T LB? If so do I need to mark or indicate which wire is the true ground coming from box, and which is heading to another receptacle?

Comment: No, you don't need to mark them. Like you said just run up to the general receptacle and come back to the Tee and then on to the pump receptacle. There is no "true" ground since they are connected together they are the same wire.